# Accessing a field through a GenericForeignKey in a django template formset

Tags: python, django, django-templates, generic-foreign-key

Suppose I have the following **model**:

```
class Holder(models.Model):
    other_field = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    object_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = GenericForeignKey('object_type', 'object_id')
```

Then **in views.py**, I have created a formset for Holder, and passed it to the template:

```
formset = modelformset_factory(Holder, fields =('other_field',))
data = {'formset': formset}
```

In **template.html**, I want to access one field of the related object. I have tried with:

```
{% for form in formset %}
     {{ form.object.related_field }}
     {{ form.other_field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then, *other_field* is displayed but *related_field* is not. How could I display the value in *related_field* in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved it by using the formset *instance*:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.instance.object.related_field }}
    {{ form.other_field }}
{% endfor %}
```